# how to take a screenshot with bitmap on iOS

Tags: ios, bitmap

I have a feature, I want to take a screenshot of a UIView(called "arrangeView" in my codes). and send the picture to my server, and then I will print it, so I want a high quantity picture..

My codes:

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(arrangeView.frame.size);
    [arrangeView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    //save and send method
    [self saveImage:newImage WithName:imgTitle];
```

With these codes I have 2 issues:

1. the picture quality is too low. because after I uploaded to the
   server, I will print it. but the picture I got with the codes only
   20~40k, it is too small to print.
2. one friend told me that the app store don't alow app take a screenshot and send it to the server. he told me to use bitmap.

And I searched in google, I don't find a good solution for it. Would someone help?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You should show also your "saveImage"-Method

Comment: my saveImage method just upload the newImage to the server. What I want to ask just how to get a high quality "newImage"

Answer (score 1):

Screen shot you get will be of same resolution as you main screen size i.e If it is iPhone 5s it will be 640 x 1136. Best way to get screen shot is:

`UIView *screenShotView = [arrangeView snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];`